# Stuff function for multiple columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have some queries to stuff a specific column.

Query 1:

```
with cte as 
(
    select distinct
        w.Work_WorkID, k.Name as "Secretariat_Attendees"  
    from 
         d,  m,  s,  w,  a,  k
    where  
        d.DataID = m.Map_MapObjID 
        and m.Map_MapID = s.SubWork_MapID 
        and s.SubWork_WorkID = w.Work_WorkID
        and w.Work_WorkID = a.WF_ID 
        and d.DataID = 35269818 
        and a.WF_AttrID = 17 
        and k.ID = a.WF_ValInt
)
select distinct 
    t2.Work_WorkID,
    stuff((select N' ; ' + Secretariat_Attendees
           from (select Work_WorkID, Secretariat_Attendees
                 from cte t1 
                 where t1.Work_WorkID = t2.Work_WorkID) AS t  
           for xml path('')), 1, 2, '') + N'' Secretariat_Attendees 
from cte t2;
```

Query 1 output:

```
Work_WorkID  Secretariat_Attendees
----------------------------------------------------
35273587     Admin CEO Office ; BD_TestUser ; Diana
35277687     10023165 ; 10036755 ; 10075193
```

Query 2:

```
    with cte as (
select  Distinct w.Work_WorkID,k.Name as  "Committee_Attendees"  from  d, m, s, w, a, k
    where d.DataID=m.Map_MapObjID and m.Map_MapID=s.SubWork_MapID and s.SubWork_WorkID=w.Work_WorkID
    and w.Work_WorkID=a.WF_ID and d.DataID=35269818 and a.WF_AttrID=5 and k.ID=a.WF_ValInt
)
select distinct t2.Work_WorkID,
    stuff((select N' ; ' + Committee_Attendees
       from (select Work_WorkID, Committee_Attendees
          from cte t1 where t1.Work_WorkID = t2.Work_WorkID) AS t  
       for xml path('')
    ), 1, 2, '') + N'' Committee_Attendees from cte t2;
```

Query 2 Output:

```
Work_WorkID Committee_Attendees
35273587     Deva ; User 1 
35277687     User3 ; User 4
```

How do I combine both these query into one to get the below desired output based on Work_WorkID?

```
Work_WorkID  Secretariat_Attendees                          Committee_Attendees
35273587     Admin CEO Office ; BD_TestUser ; Diana         Deva ; User 1 
35277687     10023165 ; 10036755 ; 10075193                 User3 ; User 4
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**over 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only difference between the two queries looks like WF_AttrID column. I moved this predicate to the sub queries. you can try this. And I also changed your table joins syntax to `JOIN`

```
with cte as 
(
    select distinct
        w.Work_WorkID, k.Name as "Attendees", a.WF_AttrID  
    from 
        DTree d
        INNER JOIN WMap m ON d.DataID = m.Map_MapObjID
        INNER JOIN WSubWork s ON m.Map_MapID = s.SubWork_MapID 
        INNER JOIN WWork w ON s.SubWork_WorkID = w.Work_WorkID
        INNER JOIN WFAttrData a ON w.Work_WorkID = a.WF_ID 
        INNER JOIN KUAF k ON  k.ID = a.WF_ValInt
    where  
        d.DataID = 35269818 
        and a.WF_AttrID IN( 5 ,17 )
)
select distinct 
    t2.Work_WorkID,
    stuff((select N' ; ' + Secretariat_Attendees
           from (select Work_WorkID, t1.Attendees AS Secretariat_Attendees
                 from cte t1 
                 where t1.Work_WorkID = t2.Work_WorkID AND t1.WF_AttrID = 17) AS t  
           for xml path('')), 1, 2, '') + N'' Secretariat_Attendees,
    stuff((select N' ; ' + Committee_Attendees
       from (select Work_WorkID, t1.Attendees AS Committee_Attendees
          from cte t1 where t1.Work_WorkID = t2.Work_WorkID AND t1.WF_AttrID = 5) AS t  
       for xml path('')
    ), 1, 2, '') + N'' Committee_Attendees 
from cte t2;
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a simple join. If your difficulty stems from combining them into a single query, all you have to do is replace the second query's cte name to cte2, put the ctes together in the beginning, and use both queries as derived tables:

```
with cte as(
....first query cte....
)
,cte2 as(
....second query cte
)
select *
from
(
    ....query 1.....
)t1
inner join
(
    ......query 2 but "cte2" instead of "cte"....
)t2 on t1.Work_WorkID=t2.Work_WorkID
```

This is a fast, unoptimized answer. I get the feeling the ctes and the queries have common, optimizable parts. Also, please stop using the onld join notation (`from table1,table2,table3.....`) and start using `join`, you can find reasons all over the internet.